# Why isn't jQuery handling id and selector passed?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an id `"#post0"`

and a class `"reply"`

When I do:

```
 var rep = ".reply";
 $(rep).toggle(400);
```

All components with class "reply" toggle.

However when I do:

```
var rep = "#post0.reply";
$(rep).toggle(400);
```

Nothing happens to the elements with class reply and post0 ...instead of toggling them

Help is appreciated!

Comment: When that code what? What does the markup actually look like? Why have you provided only snippets instead of a complete minimal test case?

Comment: Really sorry! somehow the rest of my description got clipped off. Edited now..the problem is that nothing happens when i execute that code.

Answer (score 3):

get all elements of class "reply"

```
$(".reply")
```

example:

```
<span class="reply">match</span>
```

---

return all elements that has id "post0" AND has a class "reply". note that there are NO SPACES between selectors. an element matches only when they have all "chained" selectors

```
$("#post0.reply")
```

example:

```
<span id="post0" class="reply">match</span>
```

---

return all elements that have a class "reply" that is a descendant of an element with id "post0" note that THERE IS A SPACE in between selectors

```
$("#post0 .reply")
```

example:

```
<div id="post0">
    <span class="reply">span match</span>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem is that when i execute that code No toggle happens. Sorry my initial description got chopped off! Appreciate any help you can offer wrt debugging

Comment: @algorithmicCoder try `console.log($("#post0.reply"))` to see if it returns your targets.

Answer (score 2):

`$("#post0.reply")` returns elements which has the id `post0` and class `reply`.

`$(".reply")` returns elements which has class `reply`.

`$("#post0 .reply")` returns elements with class `reply` which are nested under an element with id `post0`.

Answer (score 0):

The below JSFiddle works for me:

http://jsfiddle.net/9V7v8/

When you say your element ID is "#post0"; is the hash actually in the ID field?  Try removing the hash from the id field; so:

```
<p id="#post0"...
```

Becomes:

```
<p id="post0"...
```

Keep the # prefixed to the ID in the javascript though; this tells JQuery that it's looking for an ID; so the selector should still be:

```
var rep = "#post0.reply";
```